# Is it proper to add an extension to UIViewController class, or is there a preferred way of adding another method to an established Swift Class?

Tags: swift

I have an iOS app with multiple subclasses of UIViewControllers. There are many type of UIAlertControllers I might need to use based on user interaction, internet connection, and catching any other fatal errors.

So I wrote the extension for UIViewController below, which works just fine. And I can call from any of my UIViewControllers as simply as:

```
myErrors(error: MyErrors.e1.rawValue, title: "Internet Error", msg: "Unable to connect to Internet\nTry Again?")
```

While this works, I do not know if it's proper to add an extension to UIViewController. Is this considered bad practice? Is there another way I should be pursuing this?

```
extension UIViewController {
    func myErrors(error: MyErrors, title: String, msg: String)
    {
        var title = ""
        var message = ""
        
        switch error {
        case .e1:
            title = String(format: "%@", title)
            message = String(format: "Database Error %03d%@\n", error.rawValue, msg)
        case .e2:
            title = String(format: "%@", title)
            message = String(format: "Internet Error %03d%@\n", error.rawValue, msg)
        case .e3:
            title = String(format: "%@", title)
            message = String(format: "User Error %03d%@\n", error.rawValue, msg)
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        switch error {
        case .e1:
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .init(rawValue: 0)!, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                // ..log error
                //...proceed to code based on No ....
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .init(rawValue: 0)!, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                // ..log error
                //...code based on Yes ....
            }))
        case .e2:
                // No user option availabe in this alert, just OK
                // ... do all logging of errors
                // proceed
        case .e3:
                // Add specific acctions to this error
                // ... do all logging of errors
                // proceed
        }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a brilliant practice.

Comment: @vadian Forgive the redundancy, so it's ok to do it this way, as opposed to protocols, and delegates? Just checking since am still green around my Swift gills.
Also, how can I mark your answer as correct since it's just a comment?

Comment: It depends on your needs. Delegates are not appropriate because usually two different classes are involved with the delegate pattern. A protocol gives you finer control which objects should conform to, but if you just want to extend the functionality of all instances of a class an extension is the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer are in the 2 comments from **Vadian**

Vadian:

> It's a brilliant practice

Me:

> Forgive the redundancy, so it's ok to do it this way, as opposed to
> protocols, and delegates? Just checking since am still green around my
> Swift gills. Also, how can I mark your answer as correct since it's
> just a comment?

Vadian

> It depends on your needs. Delegates are not appropriate because
> usually two different classes are involved with the delegate pattern.
> A protocol gives you finer control which objects should conform to,
> but if you just want to extend the functionality of all instances of a
> class an extension is the best choice. –

Answer (score 0):

You can create protocol+extension, otherwise you will have access to myError method even you don't need it for particular UIViewController.

```
protocol ErrorPresenting {
   func presentAlert(for error: MyErrors, title: String, msg: String)
}

extension ErrorPresenting where Self: UIViewController {
   func presentAlert(for error: MyErrors, title: String, msg: String) {
    // Since you state that this extensions for UIViewController, you can reach view.
    // Put your method here.
    view.present(alert, animated: true)
   }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, ErrorPresenting {
// You can reach presentAlert method from this controller now.
}
```